# issue in httpurlconnection getting status 500

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to login through url and i am getting status code 500 in httpurlconnevtion

```
public static String excutePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters)
  {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
    try {
      //Create connection
      url = new URL(targetURL);
      connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
           "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");    
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
               Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  
      connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", ""); 
      connection.setUseCaches (false);
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setDoOutput(true);

      //Send request
      DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                  connection.getOutputStream ());
      wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
      wr.flush ();
      wr.close ();

      System.out.println("status :"+connection.getResponseCode());
      System.out.println("getErrorStream() :"+connection.getErrorStream());
      //Get Response    
      InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      String line;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
      }
      rd.close();
      return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;

    } finally {

      if(connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect(); 
      }
    }
  }
```

and my params are

```
String urlParameters =
                        "pwd1=" + URLEncoder.encode("DEMO123", "UTF-8") +
                        "&badge=" + URLEncoder.encode("1233", "UTF-8");
```

i am getting logcat

```
status :500
getErrorStream() :libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream@417bc5c0
```

thank you

```
**EDITED 2**
```

I have also try with

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

        // Add badge
        dos.writeBytes(LINE_START + BOUNDRY + LINE_END);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='badge';");
        dos.writeBytes(LINE_END + LINE_END);
        dos.writeBytes("1233");
        dos.writeBytes(LINE_END);

        // Add password
        dos.writeBytes(LINE_START + BOUNDRY + LINE_END);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='pwd1';");
        dos.writeBytes(LINE_END + LINE_END);
        dos.writeBytes("DEMO123");
        dos.writeBytes(LINE_END);
```

Answer (score 1):

`500` denotes an `Internal Server Error`. There is probably no error on your side, it's on the server. Even if you are sending something incorrectly and it's causing the server to return 500, it's still a server problem.

**Edit:**
Okey, the server should rather return something like `400 Bad Request` instead of `500 Internal Server Error` but I found your error now:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));

...

//Send request
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
```

The problem here is that your first get the the bytes from `urlParameters` using `getBytes` which (quoting javadoc):

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset

And then you write the bytes using `DataOutputStream.writeBytes` which (quoting javadoc):

> Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by discarding its high eight bits.

In summary, your `Content-Length` doesn't match the data. So the server returns you the

> java.io.IOException: exceeded content-length limit of 20 bytes

**Solution:**

```
//consider urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8") method instead of using default encoding
byte[] bodyData = urlParameters.getBytes(); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(bodyData.length));

...

//Send request
InputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
out.write(bodyData);
```

**Edit 2:**
Edit 1 is definitely valid, however, looking over the problem again, I believe the error is definitely caused by the server. I think the server is returning a bad `Content-Length` header and, when the data is read on Android, the system realizes there is more data coming from the server than it should be by the `Content-Length` and throws an exception, also replacing the status code by 500 because it really is a server error.

**Edit 3:**

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "");
```

Instead of setting `Content-Language` which is not neccessary here, you should set `Content-Encoding` to `UTF-8` and instead of empty `Accept-Encoding`, you should add the real expected MIME-type. I believe this is a server error, but you maybe it won't appear if you set the request headers correctly.

Comment: thank you, java.io.IOException: exceeded content-length limit of 20 bytes is there any issue

Comment: it is working perfectly with ios and i have added server code in my question plz check

Comment: how to synchronous request on server? you have any idea?

Comment: its still same issue, you have any idea abt synchronous request

Comment: I have added new code plz check my question, i have edited it

Comment: @test Avoid `DataOutputStream.writeByte` at all cost. Even if my answer still doesn't work for you, you should definitely use it because it fixes at least one error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26035/discussion-between-test-and-sulthan)

Answer (score 0):

Status code `500` means `Internal Server Error`. Why this is thrown at you, only the server behind `targetURL` knows.

Verify that you're making correct usage of the API. Taking a look at the response's body (besides the status code) may provide a hint.

Comment: @Android check connection.getErrorStream();